# C++ no match for ‘operator=’

Tags: c++, vector, operators, overloading

I've created a class to simulate the behavior of vector of int, because every time I read or write some value, also a read and write counter should be incremented to keep track of its usage. I can’t change the code in main.cpp other than from the type “int” to the type “MyInt”, that's why I'm trying to overload the [] operator to read inside the brackets and pass the operation to a second one, using a wrapper class. The error I got is:

> no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘MyInt’ and ‘int’)

so it looks like that the intercept of the assignment of the wrapper class doesn't work.
I've also overloaded the "new []" operator for the dynamic declaration and it seems to work properly. Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is that the overloaded `operator=` that you've provided is for class `wrapper` and not `MyInt`.

Comment: Your indexing operator is never called, why would it be, you are indexing an array, not `MyInt` object. Try e.g. `V[3][0] = 8;`

Comment: All of this usage of `new[]`, where does `delete[]` come into play?

Comment: Why do you want `new MyInt[10]` to construct one "vector" of 10 ints? Are you going to `#define int MyInt` or something equally obnoxious?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```cpp
    V = new MyInt[10];
```

`V` is an array of MyInt, so when you're trying to access the third index by `V[3]`, you're not calling the overloaded operator[] but accessing the third element of the array, you can do this and see that the type of `elem` is `MyInt` and not `MyInt::wrapper`:

```cpp
auto elem = V[3];
```

You can simply solve this by:

```cpp
    (*V)[3] = 3;
    // or
    V[0][3] = 3;
```

But this is a terrible way to make a vector, you should just use `std::vector` or re-design it.

Comment: Thanks! With V[0][3] it works, but is there a way to perform the same access using just "V[3]" so I don't have to write V[0][3]? I would like to simulate the behavior of an array of int being allocated while in reality it's not. Unfortunately, I can't change the code in main other than from the type "Int" to "MyInt".

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that, maybe you shouldn't use the new[] operator, just pass the size to MyInt ctor and allocate the array there instead. Don't overcomplicate things that could be done simpler

Comment: Unfortunately, my class should work in future as a library, finding and replace in code every vector from "int" to "MyInt". The only changes I can make other than that are in "MyInt.h", that's why. If you have any suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that the overloaded `operator=` that you've provided is for class `wrapper` and not `MyInt`. Now, the type of the expression `V[3]` is `MyInt` and since there is no `MyInt::operator=`, you get the mentioned error for `V[3] = 8`.

To **solve** this, change `V[3]` to `(*V)[3]` so that now, the type of the expression `*V` is `MyInt` and that of `(*V)[3]` is `wrapper` and since there is an `MyInt::wrapper::operator=` available, this will work.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to leave V[3] in main.cpp as it is and change the code in "MyInt.h" to make it work somehow?

Comment: @Opaco You're welcome. I don't think so. Though can possible be a way if you overload `operator*` for `MyInt` but that'll make the code worse.

Comment: Thanks again. How would you overload the operator* to make it work? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Opaco Basically, the overloaded `MyInt::operator*` can return a `wrapper` object so that `wrapper::opeartor[]` can be used. Something like that. Not entirely sure if that is possible but i just wanted to say it so that you can try it and somehow make it work. But doing that would make the code very unintuitive as `MyInt::operator*` should in theory return a `MyInt`.

Comment: And "MyInt::operator*" can return a wrapper object? You are suggesting something like

test& operator*( ){

    return wrapper(*this);
}

Comment: @Opaco Yes, except that the return type would be `wrapper&` instead of `test&`.

Comment: @Opaco You're welcome. I noticed that there are 2 answers posted to your new question  one(or both) of which should solve your issue.

Comment: Which one? Unfortunately I think they have misunderstood the question (probably not well formulated) since I need to return a wrapper object from indirection overload not to overload equals or square bracket operator. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: @Opaco I am talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071540/c-overload-indirection-operator-to-return-another-class-object) one. Currently, i'm quite busy and also it's around midnight here so probably go to sleep soon. So won't be able to help.