# C++ return another class object

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, indirection

Yes I know it sounds weird, but I'm looking for a way to overwrite the indirection operator to return another class object. Let me explain better:

In *main.cpp* I got

```
MyInt *V = new MyInt[10];
(*V)[3]=10;
```

but I would like to have it like:

```
MyInt *V = new MyInt[10];
V[3]=10;
```

In *MyInt.h* I've used a wrapper to catch and remove the square brackets of MyInt class and then overload the "=" operator. That's because I need a class that could store the vector and also a counter of its usage inside it. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070365/c-no-match-for-operator-with-custom-class-and-operator-overload/74070574?noredirect=1#comment130779748_74070574).

*MyInt.h*

```
wrapper operator[] ( std::size_t i ) { return wrapper( *this, i ) ; }
```

The work flow is "MyInt::wrapper::operator=".
Now it works but I would like to get rid of (*V). Would be possible to remove it by overloading the indirection operator to return a wrapper object that could be passed to "wrapper::operator=" then?
I was thinking something like:

```
MyInt& operator*(){
    return wrapper(*this)
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get `"error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘MyInt&’ from an rvalue of type ‘test::wrapper’"`. I know that the indirection operator should return the same class, but I really need it that way. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you would like `MyInt V = new MyInt[10];` to compile? If so, that's easy. Sure that's what you want? `V` wouldn't know how many elements it's pointing at though.

Comment: `(*V)[3] = 10;` is calling `operator[]` of the first in your array of 10 `MyInt`s to get *something*, and then calling that *something*s `operator=(int)`. Is that what you want? `V[3]=10;` looks more normal, in that you are calling `operator=(int)` on the forth `MyInt`

Comment: Just to make sure: you want `V` to be an array of 10 `MyInt`s (and not to make one `MyInt` calling constructor taking single `int`)?

Comment: With the new syntax, you're not specifying _which_ of the 10 `MyInt`s you're acting on. You have to specify which `MyInt` you want. The closest syntax would be `V[0][3]=10;`, to edit the `MyInt` at the 0th index. Not an answer, because I suspect you've written the wrong question.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that this is what you need? To me this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer was written when OPs question was:

> I would like to have it like:
>
> ```
> MyInt V = new MyInt[10];
> V[3]=10;
> ```

I'll leave this answer up in case anyone is interested in a solution for that.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

class MyInt {
public:
    MyInt() = default;
    MyInt(MyInt* d) : data(d) {} // constructor taking a `MyInt*`
    // ... rule of 5 implementation needed here ...

    MyInt& operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }
    MyInt& operator=(int) { return *this; }

private:
    MyInt* data = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    MyInt V = new MyInt[10];
    V[3]=10;
}
```

Note that there's no way for `V` to know how many elements `data` is pointing at.

Comment: Hello Ted, there was a typo in the OP. You might have answer another (harder) question ;)

Comment: @YSC Oh... :-) Jeez, did this question shape-shift a couple of times? I answered _"edit 2"_ of this question it seems :-)

Comment: Yes it did. I still think this is a nice answer, please do not remove it (maybe add a note).

Comment: @YSC Good idea. Note added.

Answer (score 1):

Following the link to your earlier question, and the requirements you've added there, `V[3]` is undefined behaviour.

You have changed the meaning of `new []` to return a pointer to a single object.

You need to completely rethink your design, such that there are 10 `MyInt` objects for `V` to point to.

```
struct MyCounts
{
    int num_read = 0;
    int num_write = 0;
};

class MyInt
{
    int value;
    MyCounts * counts;

    static void* operator new[](size_t n){
        void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(MyCounts) + n * sizeof(MyInt));
        MyCounts * counts = new (ptr) MyCounts;
        ptr = static_cast<void *>(counts + 1);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, ptr += sizeof(MyInt)) {
            new (ptr) MyInt{ counts };
        }
        return static_cast<void *>(counts + 1);
    }

    static void* operator delete[](void* ptr, size_t n){
        for (MyInt * last = reinterpret_cast<MyInt *>(ptr) + n; --last != ptr; ) {
            last->~MyInt();
        }
        ptr -= sizeof(MyCounts);
        reinterpret_cast<MyCounts *>(ptr)->~MyCounts();
        free(ptr);
    }
public:
    MyInt& operator=(int i) { value = i; ++counts->num_write; return *this; }
    operator int() const { ++counts->num_read; return value; }
};
```

Comment: I **lol**ed so this must be worth an upvote. I hope this is what OP wants so that discussing the XY elephant in the room becomes the next obvious step.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, this really shouldn't be what they end up with

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have it like:
>
> ```
> MyInt* V = new MyInt[10];
> V[3]=10;
> ```

You need `MyInt` to implement an `operator=` taking an int to "write" to it, and a conversion oeprator to "read" from it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct MyInt
{
    int value;
    MyInt& operator=(int v) { value = v; return *this; }
    operator int() const { return value; };
};


int main()
{
    MyInt *V = new MyInt[10];
    V[3]=10;
    std::cout << V[3] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks more like what OP needs. :-) +1

Comment: This is 100% unrelated behavior than the `(*V)[3]=10;` syntax OP is using today

Comment: Both of you: a [mcve] would help get better answers. As far as I understand OP's needs, I've answered the question. Please tag me if an update or a new question is asked.